# How to share tokio::net::TcpStream act on it concurrently?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a requirement to send and receive normal data on the same `TcpStream`, while sending heartbeat data at regular intervals. In the current implementation, I used `Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>`, but it compiled with errors:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8888").await.unwrap();
    let stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream));

    let common_stream = stream.clone();
    let handler1 = tokio::spawn(async {
        loop {
            let mut stream = common_stream.lock().unwrap();
            let mut buf = [0u8; 10];
            stream.read_exact(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            buf.reverse();
            stream.write(&buf).await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    let heartbeat_stream = stream.clone();
    let handler2 = tokio::spawn(async {
        loop {
            let mut stream = heartbeat_stream.lock().unwrap();
            stream.write_u8(1).await.unwrap();

            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));
        }
    });

    handler1.await?;
    handler2.await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:14:20
    |
14  |     let handler1 = tokio::spawn(async {
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio::net::TcpStream>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\main.rs:20:31
    |
16  |             let mut stream = common_stream.lock().unwrap();
    |                 ---------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio::net::TcpStream>` which is not `Send`
...
20  |             stream.write(&buf).await.unwrap();
    |                               ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `mut stream` maybe used later
21  |         }
    |         - `mut stream` is later dropped here
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> .cargo\registry\src\mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd\tokio-1.17.0\src\task\spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`

error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:25:20
    |
25  |     let handler2 = tokio::spawn(async {
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = help: within `impl Future<Output = [async output]>`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio::net::TcpStream>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
   --> src\main.rs:28:31
    |
27  |             let mut stream = heartbeat_stream.lock().unwrap();
    |                 ---------- has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, tokio::net::TcpStream>` which is not `Send`
28  |             stream.write_u8(1).await.unwrap();
    |                               ^^^^^^ await occurs here, with `mut stream` maybe used later
...
31  |         }
    |         - `mut stream` is later dropped here
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> .cargo\registry\src\mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn-df7c3c540f42cdbd\tokio-1.17.0\src\task\spawn.rs:127:21
    |
127 |         T: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `tokio::spawn`
```

How can these errors be fixed or is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that splits the stream to two parts for reading and writing plus does in a loop:

- waiting for heartbeat events and sends a byte to write half of stream when this happens
- waits data from read half (10 bytes), reverses it and writes again to write half

Also this does not spawn threads and does everything nicely in current one without locks.

```
use anyhow::Result;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8888").await?;
    let (mut read, mut write) = stream.split();
    let mut heartbeat_interval = tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_millis(200));
    let mut buf = [0u8; 10];

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            _ = heartbeat_interval.tick() => {
                write.write(&[1]).await?;
            }

            result = read.read_exact(&mut buf) => {
                let _bytes_read = result?;
                buf.reverse();
                write.write(&buf).await?;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and clear implementation. Thank you very much. It looks like I still have to study tokio's documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Several errors in your code, although the idea behind it is almost good. You should use any available tool in async as possible. Some of the needed/desired changes:

- Use `tokio::time::sleep` because it is async, otherwise the call is blocking
- Use an async version of mutex (the one from `futures` crate for example)
- Use some kind of generic error handling (`anyhow` would help)

```rust
use futures::lock::Mutex;
use anyhow::Error;
use tokio::time::sleep;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8888").await.unwrap();
    let stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream));

    let common_stream = stream.clone();
    let handler1 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut stream = common_stream.lock().await;
            let mut buf = [0u8; 10];
            stream.read_exact(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
            buf.reverse();
            stream.write(&buf).await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    let heartbeat_stream = stream.clone();
    let handler2 = tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            let mut stream = heartbeat_stream.lock().await;
            stream.write_u8(1).await.unwrap();

            sleep(Duration::from_millis(200)).await;
        }
    });

    handler1.await?;
    handler2.await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=125245806acaff0d7a53f9ed25a4d8f9)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [tokio documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read_exact)
the `read_exact` method is not cancellation safe. In my understanding, when the `select` cancels the `read_exact` branch, there might be some bytes already read into the `buf`, which will be overwritten in the next loop. Therefore, the accepted answer may lead to data loss.

PS. I would have written this as a comment, but my reputation is too low to do that.